# Include space in EF Core Startswith

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When doing an EF Core query with `StartsWith`, then space is not included e.g. this query (notice space after Bob):

```
var query = _context.Persons
                    .Where(p => p.FullName.StartsWith("Bob ")
                    .Select(p => p.FullName);
```

will include Bobby, Bobfish and Bobwhatever because the SQL uses `LEN('Bob ')` that is 3 because LEN does not include trailing spaces.

What is the trick to include spaces?

Comment: Just a guess, but would `&nbsp;` work here?

Comment: this is sort of an autocompleter that goes to the database, in the database the name is e.g. "Bob Marley" and in the autocompleter and send via web space is briefly URL encoded, but once it hits my code it is also a space

Comment: I guess you'll need to force a `LIKE` query here. I don't remember the exact syntax but something like this `.Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.FullName, "Bob %")

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. What EF Core version and database do you use? For SQLite + EF Core 7 `WHERE "m"."Name" LIKE 'Bob %'` is correctly generated.

Comment: @GuruStron using the latest 7.0.8. But this is interesting. I had the issue one some tables where I have includes and a little bit more, so I will try to see if I can make a few extra examples and see if it was becaue of that. The SQL in Profiles was:  WHERE @__pre_0 = N'''' OR LEFT([v].[Adresse], LEN(@__pre_0)) = @__pre_0

Comment: database is Sql Server Express: 16.0.1000.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `LIKE` explicitly via [`EF.Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.functions?view=efcore-7.0):

```cs
var query = _context.Persons
    .Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.FullName, "Bob %"))
    .Select(p => p.FullName);
```

Comment: That works! Marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to use [DbFunctions.Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctionsextensions-like(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-string-system-string)) to implement SQL native `LIKE` filtering:

```
var query = _context.Persons
                    .Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.FullName, "Bob %")) 
                    .Select(p => p.FullName);
```

---

This is based on the EF6 solution using [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex?view=netframework-4.8.1) that allows you to use a SQL `LIKE` pattern to match, so we can bypass the LINQ to SQL implementation that ignores the whitespace:

```
var query = _context.Persons
                    .Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("Bob %", p.FullName) > 0) 
                    .Select(p => p.FullName);
```

> `> 0` is correct in this instance because `PatIndex` returns a 1-based ordinal for where the pattern was found. If there are no matches, the result will be `0`. In the case of a *StartsWith* pattern, the result will *always be **1** or **0***.

If the search pattern is parameterised then we just need to append the `%` wildcard character to the end:

```
var query = _context.MyTable
    .Where(v => v.Adresse.StartsWith(pre + "%"))
    .Select(v => $"{v.Adresse}").Take(10);
```

or you can inject this into it's own explicit variable:

```
var searchExp = pre + "%";
var query = _context.MyTable
    .Where(v => v.Adresse.StartsWith(searchExp))
    .Select(v => $"{v.Adresse}").Take(10);
```

Comment: I think that would work for 4.8... I would prefer something that works with 7.0

Comment: There wouldn't be any benefit to `=1` vs `>0`  when using `PatIndex,`  but yes the returned value is only going to be 1 or 0. From a purist point of view I would actually argue that `!= 0` is more correct than either of the other two. If your pattern might have a wildcard prefix, and you still wanted to enforce _StartsWith_ only, then yes `=1` will override `"%Bob %"` behaving like a _Contains_